# Is there a way to setTitle on a UIButton that updates all UIControlStates at once?

Tags: iphone, swift

I have a UIButton, and I'd like to update its title, but I'd rather not have to always do it for each and every state like the following:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

According to the documentation you should only need to call:

In Objective-C:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

In Swift:

```
myButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
```

The UIButton docs explain why:

> In general, if a property is not specified for a state, the default is to use the UIControlStateNormal value. If the value for UIControlStateNormal is not set, then the property defaults to a system value. Therefore, at a minimum, you should set the value for the normal state.

Namely, that if you only set the normal value the other states will refer to it when being set.

Comment: That's not what I experience

Comment: This is also not true for buttons of type `.custom`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61159133/826946 below regarding situations which involve custom colors for the title text

Answer (score 6):

or you can setTitle by :

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Why would you want to do it this way?

Comment: to setup title of multiple state button in one line.

Comment: That's the exact way for all controls. UI Slider does not change in all states. helpful

Comment: That is not working because state is `NS_OPTIONS`. If you use `UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted`, you can not get title visible when button shows.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a category for UIButton:

```
@implementation UIButton (Addition)
-(void)setTitleForAllStates:(NSString *)title {
     //you can add/remove this area : UIControlStateApplication, UIControlStateDisabled, UIControlStateReserved
     [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateSelected];
     [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

## 2019

It's just

```
yourButton.setTitle("Click me", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer:

```
button.setTitle("All", for: .normal)
```

or

```
button.setTitle("All", for: [])
```

is not correct in general, because it works only if the title for some state is not already set. For example:

```
button.setTitle("N", for: .normal)
button.setTitle("HL", for: .highlighted)
button.setTitle("All", for: .normal)
```

After this code button still have title "HL" for highlighted state.
So to change title for all used states in general case, you have to loop through all these states:

```
let states: [UIControl.State] = [.normal, .highlighted, .selected, [.highlighted, .selected]]
for state in states {
  button.setTitle("All", for: state)
}
```

(If  you use other states e.g. .disabled, you have to add they combinations  to loop as well)

**Note**: UIControl.State is a Set of options, so setting the title with:

```
button.setTitle("All", for: [.selected, .highlighted])
```

does not set title "All" for both selected and highlighted states, instead it sets the title "All" for the combined state which is **selected and highlighte**d at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! If you're only setting the color once, this can be done in Interface builder but with the same insight - you need to set the color for each and every state.